# Trying to seed Neo4j database

Tags: php, laravel, neo4j

I am trying to seed a neo4j database (for the first time) through Faker, NeoEloquent and Eloquent's Seeder class. It makes a retailer, 2 companies, some products and relates then together.

### Relations

```
Retailer -> Many-Many -> Product
Retailer -> One-Many  -> Company
Company  -> One-Many  -> Product
```

### Code

```
public function run()
{
    Eloquent::unguard();

    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

// Retailer

    Retailer::createWith([
        [
            'name'      => $faker->company
        ],
        [
            'companies' => 
            [
                [
                    'company_id' => $faker->randomNumber(8), 
                    'name'       => $faker->company, 'active' => 1
                ],
                [
                    'company_id' => $faker->randomNumber(8), 
                    'name' => $faker->company, 'active' => 1
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);

// Products

    for ($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++)
    {
        for ($j = 1; $j < $faker->numberBetween(1,3); $j++)
        {
            $product = Product::create([
                'product_id' => $faker->randomNumber(8),
                'name'       => $faker->name,
                'active'     => '1',
                'time_added' => $faker->date,
                'price'      => $faker->numberBetween(1,999),
            ]);
            $retailer = Retailer::find(1);
            $retailer->products()->save($product);   // error here
            $company  = Company::find($i);
            $company->products()->save($product);
        }
    }
}
```

### Error

```
{"error":
 {"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
  "message":"Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::products()",
 "file":"D:\\Swaggable\\Laravel\\app\\database\\seeds\\DatabaseSeeder.php",
 "line":62}}
```

I can't figure how to resolve it at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of:

```
$retailer->products()->save($product);
```

you should use:

```
$retailer->products->save($product);
```

And after:

```
$retailer = Retailer::find(1);
```

you should add extra check if retailer is not null for example:

```
if (is_null($retailer)) {
  die('retailer not found') 
}
```

and in case if you don't know what's id of Retailer you should use:

```
$retailer = Retailer::orderby('id', 'desc')->first();
```

to find last record in this array

Comment: is there a possibility that when the first retailer is created, its id may not be 1?

Comment: @UmairAhmed If id is set to autoincrement it depends what next autoincrement value your table contain. If you earlier had any values in this table and removed it id won't be 1

Comment: the above generates 'Trying to get property of non-object'.

Comment: replacing the line with $retailer = Retailer::all()->first() fixed the issue after. Thanks for your time.